# Gap issue with floating/inline-block elements in 2 columns

Tags: php, html, css

The page I'm working on generates a number of elements in 2 columns with a horizontal chronology as such:

1 2
3 4
5 6
7

Since columns have vertical chronology, I am not actually using columns, instead I am using a variety of either floating elements or inline-blocks.

However, since the generated elements have user specified content and therefore unpredictable heights, this causes a number of issues:

## Scenario 1

If the left element is a float, it will float to the right of other left elements if the right element is shorter, as more space is left.

[image: See illustration]

## Scenario 2

If the left element is an inline-block, it will act as if it is a float with a clear property, the difference in size between the left and the right element will remain "cleared", rather than being occupied by the right floating element.
This will result in awkward spaces in the right column, as the elements there seem to want to follow the start of a new line on inline-blocks.

[image: See illustration]

The desired end result is something that resembles scenario 2 but without the gaps. Is there any way to make the 2 columns not interfere with each other in this way?

Comment: Actually hold on, i might have misunderstood you a bit. Do you have to render those items in a certain order? (as in if you dont mind, you could render those items in two separate columns, where one column would contain items 1,3,5,7 and the other one 2,4,6) :)

Comment: No, they do not have to be rendered in that order. I even considered this exact solution myself, but I am not entirely sure how I'd go about splitting the query result object into 2 batches like that. Currently I just loop through it with the fetch_assoc() function in PHP. I am already tracking the left and the right side by simply switching a variable between 2 states inside the loop. Can you think of a way in which I could effectively store all of the results that end up in one of the two states while rendering the other?

Comment: How big datasets do you expect in there? As in how many elements rendered at once and approx how much of the data they might be?

Comment: Rather small. Probably no more than 20 boxes each making use of 2 data points (an integer and a "text" type), in reality the arrays do contain more data at the moment, but I could cut the rest off in the query with no consequences.
It's impossible to say exactly how many "sets" it will end up having though, but most likely it will never exceed about 50 sets.

Comment: Also, if you're hinting at performance related issues, I should mention that this site is expected to have very very low traffic. It's a site for a hobbyist who gets about 10 unique visitors per day, tops, with not much incentive to ever "expand". Just about any clunky fix that gets the job done will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data seems not to be of a significant size, you have two pretty simple routes to pick from.

One of them would be splitting the data set into two arrays, each holding respective items, like:

```
$arrO = [];
$arrE = [];
$odd = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  if($odd) $arrO[] = $row;
  else $arrE[] = $row;
  $odd = !$odd;
}
```

The other option would be to loop twice over the data set and pick just the rows you are interested in:

```
$results = $result->fetch_all();
$odd = true;
foreach($results as $row){
  if($odd) //print something, or whatever :)
  $odd = !$odd;
}
$odd = true;
foreach($results as $row){
  if(!$odd) //print something, or whatever :)
  $odd = !$odd;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, while using "fetch_all" I end up with regular arrays, not associative arrays. Is there an easy way to do option 2 with associative arrays? For now I just cut down the query to avoid accidentally messing up the indexes if I make changes to the database table, but I am curious to learn if this is an inherent restriction of this approach.

Comment: Check the optional parameter of `fetch_all()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php